# Creating Python script to merge broken polylines from Microstation CAD file in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, dgn

I have tried using the dissolve tool with unsplit_lines option but it does not merge the lines ... maybe there is a step I am missing?

Comment: Can you post your code Angie?

Comment: @Angle, so there are gaps between you polylines?

Comment: I do not have any code to post. In general, lets say you have street dgn (Cad file) and you open it in ArcGIS. You'll see the street lines, but they are broken in some areas. The problem is the mapper who created the dgn file did not connect all the lines. I am not allowed to attached any images so I can't show you.
look at this example: Broken line ---------------- -------------- ----------- ------- I want the Python script in ArcGis to look at the line above and combine it to one line, like--------------------------------------------------------------------- this.

Comment: Angie, if you post the image to http://imgur.com/ I will put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert you dgn layer into ar feature dataset and create a topology to bridge the road gaps.  You must have either ArcEditor or ArcInfo license level to create topologies.  After you are comfortable doing this you could create a model using the topology geoprocessing tools to automate the process.  Once you have the model set you can export it out to a python script.

[ArcGIS 10 Topology Overview](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006200000001000000.htm)

[Toplogy geoprocessing toolset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Topology_toolset/0017000000nn000000/)